# Merge rows in Excel & VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv, merge

I want to merge rows in Excel: the content to merge can be in different columns, "C" or "D" in my example. Any way I can do this using VBA? The file has ~20k rows.

**My File:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C3mo.png

[image: file]

**Goal:** *https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzvtM.png*

[image: file]

*Edit with more details:*

Some sentences from the C & D columns are divided in 2,3 and sometimes 4 rows. I would like to merge those strings at the "top" cell from their respective column, when "A" and "B" have a value.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: and by merge you mean combine the to sheets?

Comment: Please post the code you have written thus far. Note, that SO is not offering services to write VBA code for you. We are rather interested to help fellow VBA programmers to write their own code.

Comment: No, merge the content of rows on "one sheet"! Output can be on a new sheet though. See example / C&D columns

Comment: [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
Sub Merge()
    Dim ws As worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim sheet2Rng As Range: Set sheet2Rng = ws2.UsedRange
    Dim startRow As Integer: startRow = LastRow(ws) + 1
    Dim ws2RowCount As Integer: sheet2Rng.Rows.Count

    ChangeEvents False
    ws.Range("A" & startRow).Resize(ws2RowCount, 4).value = sheet2Rng.value
    ChangeEvents True
End Sub

Public Function LastRow(worksheet As worksheet) As Integer
    LastRow = worksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Function

Sub ChangeEvents(value As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify?  Are you trying to:

- Create merged cells: C1 with D1, C2 with D2, etc?  This will lose the contents of the D column.
- Take the texts in column D and append them to the end of the column C cells;
- Create a new column which contains the C + D appended texts

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Sub SquishRows()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rr As Range
    Dim rowdata As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, idx As Integer, j as Integer

    Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    sh1.Activate

    Set rng = Range("A2").Resize(sh1.UsedRange.rows.Count - 1, sh1.UsedRange.Columns.Count)

    ReDim rowdata(Application.CountA(rng.Columns(1)), rng.Columns.Count - 1)

    idx = 0
    For i = 1 To rng.rows.Count
        Set rr = rng.rows(i)
        If Len(rr.Cells(1).Text) And Len(rr.Cells(2).Text) Then
            idx = idx + 1
            For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
                rowdata(idx, j - 1) = rr.Cells(j).Text
            Next
        Else
            For j = 3 To rng.Columns.Count
                If Len(rr.Cells(j).Text) Then
                    rowdata(idx, j - 1) = rowdata(idx, j - 1) & " " & rr.Cells(j).Text
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

    'push data to Sheet2
    sh2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(rowdata, 1) + 1, UBound(rowdata, 2) + 1).Value = rowdata

    'add in header row
    sh2.Range(sh1.UsedRange.rows(1).Address).Value = sh1.UsedRange.rows(1).Value

    sh2.Activate
End Sub
```